# Help with eigen vectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am using numpy and my own excercise answers and in both i am getting totally different answers.

The matrix in question is $\begin{bmatrix}0.6 & 0.9\\0.4 & 0.1\end{bmatrix}$

could someone take me through the steps? 
I cannot seem to get to the answer of Eigenvalues of (1,-0.3), my sheet seems to assume that it is a markov matrix and therefore uses the trace and the fact that lambda_1 will always be 1 yet i cant find it through the characteristic equations.

any helps would be appreciated

Comment: Show your work. We can’t read your mind, nor should you expect anyone to try to guess where you might be going wrong.

Comment: so the characteristic equation is x^2 -0.7x-0.3 = 0

Comment: and with the quadratic formula i got x=(0.7 + (1.79)^0.5)/2 and x=(0.7 - (1.79)^0.5)/2

Comment: although to be fair i have just seen that it factorises, so thats a shame that i wasted everyones time

Comment: From $x^2-0.7x-0.3=0$ multiply both sides by $10$ and then it is easy to factor

Comment: The discriminant is equal to 1.69, not 1.79.

Answer (score 1):

Computing this in Python

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

A  = np.matrix('.6,.9;.4,.1')
w,v = LA.eig(A)

v
Out[5]: 
matrix([[ 0.91381155, -0.70710678],
        [ 0.40613847,  0.70710678]])

w
Out[6]: array([ 1. , -0.3])
```

computing this by hand

$$det(A-I\lambda) = \begin{vmatrix} 0.6 -\lambda & 0.9 \\ .4 & .1 -\lambda \end{vmatrix}  $$
$$ (0.6-\lambda)(0.1-\lambda) - (0.9) (0.4) $$

$$ \lambda^{2} -.7\lambda -.3  = $$
$$ (\lambda - 1)(\lambda+.3)$$
$$\lambda_{1} = 1, \lambda_{2} =-.3 $$

Comment: Haven't used Python/Numpy for this. Nice to see it (+1).

Answer (score 0):

To find the Eigenvalues of matrix $M$ you can compute the following:  $\det(M- \lambda I) = 0$, and then solve for the values of $\lambda$.

$$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}0.6 & 0.9\\0.4 & 0.1\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0\\0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0.6-\lambda & 0.9\\0.4 & 0.1-\lambda \end{bmatrix}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Because your haven't shown the source of your difficulty, I will
show you results from R about eigen-values and eigen-vectors of
your matrix $\mathbf{A}.$

```
A = matrix(c(.6, .9,  .4, .1), nrow=2, byrow=T);  A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.6  0.9
[2,]  0.4  0.1
eigen(A)

$values
[1]  1.0 -0.3

$vectors                      # read columns
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.9138115 -0.7071068
[2,] 0.4061385  0.7071068
```

Your matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is not a Markov transition matrix in the traditional notation,
in which rows are conditional distributions and must add to $1.$
Recently, I have seen a few texts in which transition matrices are shown
as the transpose of the classical transition matrices. Then it's the columns
of the transition matrices that need to sum to unity. If you need help
matching your matrix or its eigen-decomposition with a Markov chain,
please clarify the meaning of the matrix.

In particular, if your 2-state Markov chain has $$P(X_{i+1} = 2 | X_i = 1) = 0.4
\;\; \text{and}\;\; P(X_{i+1} = 1 | X_i = 2) = 0.9,$$ then you can find the long-run
distribution $\mathbf{\lambda}$ of this ergodic chain with the following additional computation:

```
vec = eigen(A)$vectors[,1]
lam = vec/sum(vec); lam
[1] 0.6923077 0.3076923

lam %*% t(A)                # '%*%' denotes matrix multiplication
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.6923077 0.3076923
```

The first eigenvector (smallest modulus) is *proportional* to $\lambda.$
So upon norming, we get $\lambda\mathbf{A^T} = \lambda,$ where 
$\lambda = (0.6923, 0.3077).$